# Second webservice call should abort first

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a page with an updatepanel, within this panel there some buttons to create a call to my webservice. When one button is clicked and while this request is processed another button is clicked the second call/postback waits till the first is finished and then processes the second.

Is it possible to cancel the first webservice call/postback (or at least don't wait for response) and the second call is executed immediately?

Comment: Is the web-service under your control? Is it wcf?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: One of the following can help you to organize infrastructure/dispatcher, so subsequent call cancels the one before:
task cancelation token in TPL, manuall Thread creation and Abort method, ManualResetEvent/AutoResetEvent manipulation. But of course, it is not very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that what I want doesn't have to do with the webservice itself.

This is the default behaviour of .net. But because the project uses sessionstate this behaviour is changed. When using sessionstate there only can be one postback handled at the time and when the first is finished the next one is fired.